# Why am I getting a white screen instead of map?

Tags: android, google-maps

Here is the code. I'm getting latitude and longitude in textview above the screen. googel symbols appears. but map dont appear instead a white screen appears. And i feel in this code network provider is used instead of internet provider. which is good to get a map where ever.?

MApActivity

```
 import android.app.Dialog;
 import android.location.Criteria;
 import android.location.Location;
 import android.location.LocationListener;
 import android.location.LocationManager;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
 import android.view.Menu;
 import android.widget.TextView;
 import android.widget.Toast;
  import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
 import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
 import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
 import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
 import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
 import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

 public class MapActivity extends FragmentActivity implements   LocationListener {

GoogleMap googleMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
    // Getting Google Play availability status
    int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getBaseContext());

    // Showing status
    if(status!=ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){ // Google Play Services are not available

        int requestCode = 10;
        Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, requestCode);
        dialog.show();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"No service", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }else { // Google Play Services are available

        // Getting reference to the SupportMapFragment of activity_main.xml
        SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        // Getting GoogleMap object from the fragment
        googleMap = fm.getMap();

        // Enabling MyLocation Layer of Google Map
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        // Getting LocationManager object from System Service LOCATION_SERVICE
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // Creating a criteria object to retrieve provider
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

        // Getting the name of the best provider
        String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

        // Getting Current Location
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

        if(location!=null){
            onLocationChanged(location);
        }
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 20000, 0, this);
    }
}
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    TextView tvLocation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_location);

    // Getting latitude of the current location
    double latitude = location.getLatitude();

    // Getting longitude of the current location
    double longitude = location.getLongitude();

    // Creating a LatLng object for the current location
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

    // Showing the current location in Google Map
    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

    // Zoom in the Google Map
    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10));

    // Setting latitude and longitude in the TextView tv_location
    tvLocation.setText("Latitude:" +  latitude  + ", Longitude:"+ longitude   );

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.map, menu);
    return true;
}
 }
```

Manifest.xml
I addded all the requirements correctly I guess.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.abhayatma"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
 <permission
 android:name="com.example.xxxx.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
 android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.example.xxxx.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />



<android:uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="18" />
<android:uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="18" />
 <uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    ----------------

   ------------
    <activity
        android:name=".MapActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_map" >
    </activity>


    <meta-data
 android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
 android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
            <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyBv0UVaXXYiFGWBdNb_DNSQIdkI9672IlY" />
            <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
</application>

 </manifest>
```

Comment: did you set your map api key in manifest?
did you turn on your internet connection ?

Comment: yes. I added map key. My WIFI is turned on.

Comment: did you set all permission in manifest

Comment: could you please send your manifest?

Comment: i bet you havnt set this permission:
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

Comment: I added those permissions.

Comment: Please try [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ADb5bNOFHE) step by step, you will get the google map show on the Android

Answer (score 0):

```
Please check these permission in manifest 




<permission
        android:name="info.androidhive.googlemapsv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="info.androidhive.googlemapsv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <!-- Required to show current location -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
     <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />


          <meta-data
     android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
     android:value="your api key of gooogle console" />
```